# Setting list from drools decision table

Tags: java, drools

I am using drools for implementing certain condtion.I don't know how to set the 
arraylist of the bean in action from drools decision table.For example following is my class.

```
public class Dog implements Serializable{

 private String id;
 private List<String> names;

}
```

My decision table should set the list of names based on the id paseed.How to implement this?

```
Conditon    Action
d:Dog
id          ???(what needs to be done here)
1           "tom","jack","pearl"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done in the usual way.

```
Condition    Action
d:Dog        d.getNames()
id           addAll(Arrays.asList($param))
Match id!    Add some names!   
1            "tom","jack","pearl"
```

You'll have to import Arrays or use the full class name.

Comment: I am getting following error nowThe left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable com/sample/Rule_sample_Rule_9.java (7:533) : Syntax error on token ",", invalid AssignmentOperator

Comment: My drl getting generated for decisiontable                                                  when
  d:Dog(id == "1")
 then
  d.getNames().addAll(java.util.Arrays.asList("Pearl","tom","jack"));

Answer (score 2):

If you used Spreadsheet File (.xlsx or .xls) then you can try this:

pojo calss:

```
public class CategoryEntity {

       private String type;
       private String allAction;
       private List<String> actionList; // list

       // Getters and Setters 

}
```

And Spreadsheet File like this:

[image]